# Write Dickman Function as CDF

Tags: functions

Is it possible to write the [Dickman Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DickmanFunction.html) $F(\alpha)$ & $G(\beta)$ in terms of a cumulative distribution function? I would like to play around with the variance, etc as I am interested in how it might fit a set of data I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $F(\alpha)$ function satisfies [the properties that a function must have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) in order to be considered a cumulative distribution function- of the random variable $\alpha$.
Then we have

$$F_{\alpha}(\alpha)=\begin {matrix}
0 & \alpha <0\\
\\
\int_0^{\alpha}\frac 1tF\left (\frac {t}{1-t}\right)dt & 0\le \alpha \le 1/2\\
\\
1+\ln \alpha & 1/2\le \alpha \le 1\\
\\
1& \alpha >1
\end{matrix}$$

and so the density is
$$f_{\alpha}(\alpha)=\begin {matrix}
0 & \alpha <0\\
\\
\\ \frac 1{\alpha}F\left(\frac {\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right) & 0\le \alpha \le 1/2\\
\\
\frac 1{\alpha} & 1/2\le \alpha \le 1\\
\\
0& \alpha >1
\end{matrix}$$

Then
$$E(\alpha) = \int_0^1 \alpha f_{\alpha}(\alpha)d\alpha = \int_0^{1/2} \alpha \frac 1{\alpha}F\left(\frac {\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)d\alpha + \int_{1/2}^1 \alpha \frac 1{\alpha}d\alpha$$

$$\Rightarrow E(\alpha) = \int_0^{1/2} F\left(\frac {\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)d\alpha + \frac 12$$

and

$$E(\alpha^2) = \int_0^{1/2} \alpha F\left(\frac {\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)d\alpha + \frac 38$$
and whatever else you can squeeze out of it.

Comment: @ Alecos Papadopoulos, Many thanks - this has really helped :)